# How to set invert_if_negative to fill bars to a solid color in python xlswriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am making graphics on excel from python using xls writer and want to make a graphic with green colored bars for positive values, and red for negative.

Current code seems like this:

```
chart3 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
chart3.add_series({
    'values': '=Summary!$W$2:$W$76',
    'categories': '=Summary!$A$2:$A$76',
    'gap': 4,
    'line': {'width': 1},
    'name': '=Summary!$W$1',
    'fill':   {'color': 'green'},
    'invert_if_negative': True
})
```

It differientiates positive and negative values in the graph but the negative ones are just no-colored. Is there a way to make the inverted color to be red?

Already tried with other properties like inverted_color or any syntax like that but does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need version >= 3.1.1 of XlsxWriter which supports the `invert_if_negative_color` parameter:

```py
from xlsxwriter import Workbook


workbook = Workbook("chart.xlsx")

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "column"})

worksheet.write_column("A1", [3, 2, -3, 4, -2])

chart.add_series(
    {
        "values": "=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5",
        "fill": {"color": "green"},
        "invert_if_negative": True,
        "invert_if_negative_color": "red",
    }
)

worksheet.insert_chart("C1", chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]